# How to implement a queue,

Tags: c#, struct, stack, queue

I wonder if I could count on your support in order to solve the question that consists on to make a program in C# to implement a queue or a stack using pointers.

The biggest problem is that the implementations in C++ or C do not run when I try to reuse them in C#.

For instance, when I try to use the code below in order to start the creation of a code that uses linked list in C#

```
struct cel {
   int         content;
   struct cel *prox;
};
```

The Console Application returns the following errors:

(1) 'Cel': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type
(2) Invalid token '*' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
(3) { expected
(4) Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
(5) Invalid token 'namespace' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

As I need to make this part of code to run in order to continue the other parts of implementation I really like to count on your help to sove this problem.

If you know how to implement correctly this part of code, or even, if you know how to implement a queue or a stack using pointers in C#, please, give me the complete code.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of the C# language first – this is something that Stack Overflow cannot teach you, it requires a book or (at the very least) a good tutorial. C# is completely different from both C and C++.

Comment: I respect your oppinion but I cannot agree with you. Firstly,  because if it was something so easy as you said, I already would have found the answer in one of dozens of sites that I have visited.
If you do not know the answer for a question, please, do not be stupid in order to evaluate its relevance before trying to answer.

Comment: He did not say what you are trying to do is easy, he said the language is different, using very different ways of doing things. If you want to write C or C++ code, go write C or C++ code! There is nothing wrong with those lanaguages, they are fun to write in and get the job done especially if you already know how to do what you want to do. However if you want to write C# you need to learn the basics language first, as while similar, there are some major differences you must first understand (and would be out of scope to explain here, you should pick up a book or follow a tutorial first).

Comment: Just as a simple example of the differences in the language, in C# you already use pointers everywhere by default (classes are "refrence objects" so the variables hold a refrence (a kind of smart pointer) to the real object). So basically in C# when you have a `class` instead of a `struct` pretend every `.` is really a `->`. What you are doing in your above code is work with plain raw pointers, and that is almost never done in C# unless you are in a very special case.

Comment: "please, give me the complete code" what are we, your lackeys?

Comment: @GeraldoVALeal I didn’t say it was easy (although it’s not exactly hard). And despite what you said, there are [plenty of website which show how to do it](https://www.google.com/#q=implement+a+queue+in+C%23) But you have a fundamental misunderstanding about the nature of the language, since you seem to expect that C code would just run as C# code. And for just giving you a ready-made code this isn’t the right website. This is actually explicitly spelled out in the FAQ.

Comment: C# also supports pointers in a limited extent. See Pointer types (C# Programming Guide) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx and this tutorial http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rajeshvs/PointersInCSharp11112005051624AM/PointersInCSharp.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much folks for helping me with this question that I have just solved due to your tips. Firstly, my congratulations to  Scott Chamberlain that was very patient since his first contact and gave me great explanations. Secondly, my thanks to  Konrad Rudolph that in his second contact gave me a plenty of website which show how to do it in detais. So, I just had to do some little adjustments. Finally, Tony that in his comments gave me a great link where I found complementary information for answering the question in my academic work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect that code from a specific language will work in another.
In C# you usually use references, and not pointers. First Learn the basics of C#, and then try to write more complex code.